# Wordpress REST API response - not returning results from custom taxonomy, only from title

Tags: search, rest-api

I'm trying to set up a custom search for documents on the web page.
The documents should be sortable based on their respective categories.
If one category is selected, only the documents associated with that category should show up.

This category is a custom taxonomy, called 'dokumentum_kategoria'.

Issue is, when I try to perform a search on the rest API endpoint, it seems to only search the 'title' of the given post, it does not seem to care about any other props.

The goal of this custom search is to return the documents based on 'category' and not 'title'.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
    <?php

add_action('rest_api_init', 'universityRegisterSearch2');

function universityRegisterSearch2() {
  register_rest_route('university/v2', 'search', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
    'callback' => 'universitySearchResults2'
  ));
}

function universitySearchResults2($data) {
  $mainQuery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('dokumentum'),
    's' => sanitize_text_field($data['term'])
  ));

    $results = array(
      'dokumentumok' => array(),
    );

      while($mainQuery->have_posts()) {
      $mainQuery->the_post();
   
      if (get_post_type() == 'dokumentum') {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'dokumentum_kategoria');
        $term_names = array();
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            array_push($term_names, $term->name);
        }
        array_push($results['dokumentumok'], array(
            'title' => get_the_title(),
            'postType' => get_post_type(),
            'link' => get_field('dokumentum_fajl'),
            'category' => $term_names
        ));
    }
  }

  if ($results['dokumentumok']) {
    $results['dokumentumok'] = array_values(array_unique($results['dokumentumok'], SORT_REGULAR));
    
  }
  return $results;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: WP doesn't search the names of terms or the values of post meta/ACF fields, this isn't a REST API issue, it's a general WP search feature request that's quite common and has been asked by other people lots of times

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I managed to fix the issue with SEARCH EVERYTHING

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue, as the SEARCH EVERYTHING plugin has this exact functionality. The issue was not related to WP-REST, but to the standard WordPress Search.